# Search 2 words simultaneously in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I want to searching two words ("error" , "correct") Simultaneously inside webView.
I use below code for API <16

```
    int  number_match_error=web.findAll("error");
    int number_match_ok=DeleteAccount.web.findAll("correct");

    if(number_match_error!=0)
          Toast.makeText(base_context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else  if(number_match_ok!=0)
         Toast.makeText(base_context, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This code works properly.
method findAll() returns a value.
I am using the return value, to separate

but for API>16

I Should use findAllAsync()

This function returns an empty value
So  I do not know how  search for the two words separately, inside Web View?

```
       web.findAllAsync("error");
       web.findAllAsync("correct");
       web.setFindListener(new FindListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFindResultReceived(int activeMatchOrdinal, int numberOfMatches, boolean isDoneCounting) {
//   how found    numberofMathes is for word "error" or "correct"?
});
    }
```